# Print QWebPage to pixmap

Tags: qt, printing, qtwebkit

I'm not the most experienced in Qt or desktop development, so I hope this isn't too much of an ignorant question.

I am trying to use QWebKit [1] to store a webpage to images as if printed on paper. Unfortunately it seems that QPainter works only for printing to pdf, postscript or a real printer, and QWebFrame doesn't have methods to set the media to CSS in case of rendering to a QPainter.

I can see that inside Qt QPrintPreviewWidgetPrivate uses `printer->d_func()->previewPages();` to get a preview of the images that will be sent to the printer, however this is a private method and not a publicly available API and therefore I cannot use it even if it were possible to get the images at a desired resolution.

At this point I am at a loss and might actually start delving into how QPrinter and QWebFrame interact and just re-implement the methods in hope that it isn't too big of an undertaking.

[1] Unfortunately can't upgrade to Qt5 and QWebEngine yet.